# req.query from backend turns out to be json on React front end after deployed to heroku, how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, redux, axios

This question is closely related to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745960/how-to-get-req-query-value-from-node-js-backend-to-react-redux-front-end)

Backend:

```
//route: GET /shop
//note: get all the products on shop page
//access: public
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let items

        //sort by category
        if(!req.query.category) {
            items = await Product.find()
        } else {
            items = await Product.find({category: req.query.category})
        }
        //sort by price and letter
        if(req.query.sortBy) {
            let sort ={}
            const sortByArray = req.query.sortBy.split(':')
            sort[sortByArray[0]] =[sortByArray[1]]
            items = await Product.find().sort(sort).exec()
        }

        res.json(items)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message)
        res.status(500).send('Server error')
    }
})
```

actions:

```
//get all the products
export const getProducts = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/shop${window.location.search}`)

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PRODUCTS,
            payload: res.data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_ERROR,
            payload: { msg: error.response.statusText, status: error.response.status }
        })
    }
}
```

front-end for the filter links:

```
<a href="/shop?category=music" >MUSIC</a>
```

How I get products rendering from front-end

```
import React, {useEffect, Fragment } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Loader from '../layout/Loader'
import ProductItem from './ProductItem'

import { getProducts } from '../../actions/products'
import { addToCart } from '../../actions/cart'


const Products = ({
    getProducts,
    addToCart,
    product: {
        products,
        loading
    }
}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts()
    }, [getProducts])

    return  loading ? <Loader /> : (
        <Fragment>
            <section className="products-grid">
            {products.map(product => (
                <ProductItem key={product._id} product={product} addToCart={addToCart} />
            ))}
            </section>
        </Fragment>
    )

}

Products.propTypes = {
    product: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getProducts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    addToCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    product: state.product
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getProducts, addToCart})(Products)
```

It works well in my development environment, when click on music I get it filtered like this:
[image: local environment]
 then I deployed to heruko (that means we run build etc). Now on the deployed version, when I clicked on my filtering options, they turn out to be json string, like we're getting the response from backend directly to the browser, like this:
[image: heroku]

THE URL is here:
[Heroku app](https://thirtysecondstomars.herokuapp.com/)

**I have tried**

1. adding the deployed address to the axios.get, but it didn't work
2. changing the proxy in client's json file (before it's http://localhost:5000) to the deployed app address, it didn't work either

So how do I fix this problem so it works exactly like in my dev environment?

Comment: Can you add an example of the response you are getting back? Your components seem right at first glance, so I failed to understand what exactly is happening

Comment: @JCQuintas Yes I added more code plus the pix for reference.

Comment: Ah! haha, this looks nasty, it's likely a problem with your heroku config or your routing in react. I would bet on the heroku config though. You probably want to take a look at your network tab on the devtools to see what is happening.

Comment: @JCQuintas I am also suspecting something is going on with heroku but have no idea what, and how to fix it. I checked on the network tab of the problem link and it shows no error, but the Redux devtool does say it has no store found. That says something. Because with other working pages the store would show up.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the heroku url its hosted at?

Comment: @JCQuintas  yes I am a bit reluctant to share since I am having trouble lol. But I guess we must do that since we need to debug. I will post it to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that your `backend` has the same url as your `frontend`. Which means that, when you enter the app through `myurl.com/` it will work, but if you refresh the page in lets say `myurl.com/shop` it will try to access the `backend` api.

One way to try and solve this could be to append `/api` on the backend requests. So you would get

```js
router.get('/api', async (req, res) => {...}
```

and on front

```js
const res = await axios.get(`/api/shop${window.location.search}`)
```

It might not solve everything though, but it's worth a try.

I don't have a clear info on how your structure is set, but you also might need to make a few changes in the entire frontend/backend communication.

Comment: OMG! You're my hero! I guess it works on my dev enviroment because we're running two different servers, localhost:3000 and localhost:5000, that's why the naming issue didn't seem to have conflict. Now I should remember to put everything in the back end into something called api in the future to avoid such problem.

Comment: Glad to help :)